# How can I have an index value inside an inner select in a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
 var ts = _q.GetAll()
       .Where(m => m.a == 1)
       .Select(m => new MyClass 
                    {
                    Id = ???,
                    QId = m.q
                    })
       .ToList();
```

How can I make this so that the Id field in MyClass gets an index 
value starting with 1 and incrementing for each new MyClass Created?

Note that I did try to specify .Select(m, index => etc but this 
gives me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [overload of `Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that gives you the index:

```
var ts = _q.GetAll()
   .Where(m => m.a == 1)
   .Select((m, index) => new MyClass 
                {
                    Id = index + 1,
                    QId = m.q
                })
   .ToList();
```

---

> I did try to specify .Select(m, index => etc but this gives me an error

Yes, because of the missing paranthesis.